# Editing x-axis within GGplot - TIme Series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have currently created a time series plot in GGplot2,

my current dataframe has the first column set to character type with row values such as "1998Jan", "1998Feb" and so on. The rest of the columns are numeric.

I am having problems with the x - axis as i can't seem to find a way to edit the ggplot code to show a grouping of years as the breaks, e.g. 1998 which comprises of all months within 1998.

Tl;Dr: Currently my plot just shows every single row value within that first column so there are many break, i want to create a way of limiting the number of breaks by grouping values in the first column.

Is there anything i can do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this answer is wrong, you're going to need to provide more information, for example check out how to post a minimal reproducible dataset. For now I'll assume that the column you want to use for x always has the format yyyymmm, in which case the relevant bit of your ggplot2 code could be

```
aes(x = substr(colname, 1, 4),
```

where colname is the name of your column.
This will give you the four digit year as a character, so ggplot2 will treat it as categorical. It should be ordered as you'd want, but for more flexibility you may then want to convert it to numeric (but then would want to specify it as a grouping variable).